# Categories order in vertical bar chart ( in Plotly )

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to plot horizontal bars and color them by positive / negative values. The issue is that the order of the bar is changed even though I used `categoryarray = cat`. If I remove the `color = sign` part, the order is fine. Here is my code so far:

```
library(plotly)
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table( cat = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                  val = c(12, -3, -9, 2))
dt[, sign := "p"]
dt[val < 0 , sign := "n"]
setorder(dt, -cat)

p <- plot_ly(data = dt, y = cat, x = val, type = "bar",  orientation = "h", color = sign ) %>%
  layout(title = "Some title",
         xaxis = list(categoryarray = cat, categoryorder = "array"),
         showlegend = FALSE)
p
```

And the output:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the horizontal orientation, the y-axis carries the categories. So what you need to do is to edit the y-axis inside the `layout` function instead:

```
library(plotly)
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table( cat = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                  val = c(12, -3, -9, 2))
dt[, sign := "p"]
dt[val < 0 , sign := "n"]
setorder(dt, -cat)

p <- plot_ly(data = dt, y = cat, x = val, type = "bar",  orientation = "h", color = sign) %>%
  layout(title = "Some title",
         yaxis = list(categoryarray = cat, categoryorder = "array"),
         showlegend = FALSE)
p
```

[image]